# Как в TFS отложить какую-то работу без коммита, а потом вернуться и доделать?

Tags: visual-studio, контроль-версий, tfs

Допустим, я сижу пилю фичи и все такое, но тут меня просят в этом же проекте сделать небольшую правку и выполнить публикацию.

Проблема в том, что фича над которой я кропотливо трудился еще не готова...

Т.е по сути, я должен взять проект без фичи из TFS сделать то, что меня просят сейчас сделать, опубликовать и вернуться к доработке фичи.

На ум приходит создание еще одного WorkSpace, где я выкачаю решение без своей текущей работы, поправлю и верну. Однако может быть есть какой-то другой путь джедая?

Comment: В git это делается с помощью stash. Я погуглил альтернативу в tfs - выдаёт, что это shelve. [TFS equivalent to GIT stash](http://ontocsharp.blogspot.com/2015/05/tfs-equivalent-to-git-stash.html)

Answer (score 0):

Тут стоит уточнить что используется TFVC или GIT. Но если идет речь о воркспейс, то в TFVC есть штатная функциональность для этого, называется Shelve. Документацию можно посмотреть здесь: [Suspend your work and manage your shelvesets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/suspend-your-work-manage-your-shelvesets?view=azure-devops-2020)